# Unresolved symbols when compiling jasper report

Tags: java, jasper-reports

When I attempt to compile a jrxml file created in jasper studio v6.2.0, using the jasperreports 6.2.1 library, I get the following errors:

```
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: Errors were encountered when compiling report expressions class file:
/home/david_clymer/Development/VistaShare/OutcomeTracker/HUD329902_1461778704578_563528.java:477: error: cannot find symbol
                value = CONCATENATE(((java.lang.String)field_ns058Agency_Physical_City.getValue()),",",((java.lang.String)field_ns058Agency_Physical_State.getValue()),"  ",((java.lang.String)field_ns058Agency_Ph
ysical_Zip.getValue())); //$JR_EXPR_ID=40$
                        ^
  symbol:   method CONCATENATE(String,String,String,String,String)
  location: class HUD329902_1461778704578_563528

...

9 errors
.
        at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.design.JRAbstractCompiler.compileReport(JRAbstractCompiler.java:215)
        at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperCompileManager.compile(JasperCompileManager.java:357)
        at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperCompileManager.compileToFile(JasperCompileManager.java:273)
        at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperCompileManager.compileToFile(JasperCompileManager.java:232)
        at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperCompileManager.compileReportToFile(JasperCompileManager.java:542)
        at RunReport.compileReport(RunReport.java:80)
        at RunReport.main(RunReport.java:192)
```

**How do I ensure that these functions are imported and available?**

This is the debugging I've done so far:

According to my googling, this results from the absence of `jasperreports-functions-6.2.1.jar` in the java classpath. However, in my case it most definitely *is* in the classpath, and testing shows that its classes are accessible, but the methods are not:

```
// Imports without error
import net.sf.jasperreports.functions.standard.TextFunctions;

public class Foo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Cannot resolve symbol INTEGER_VALUE
        Object foo = TextFunctions.INTEGER_VALUE;
    }
}
```

Decompiling the relevant class shows that the method is indeed there:

```
david_clymer@zapazoid:~/Development/VistaShare/OutcomeTracker/jasperreports/lib/tmp$ jar -xf ../jasperreports-functions-6.2.1.jar 
david_clymer@zapazoid:~/Development/VistaShare/OutcomeTracker/jasperreports/lib/tmp$ java -jar ../../../procyon-decompiler-0.5.30.jar net/sf/jasperreports/functions/standard/TextFunctions.class |grep -A 7 INTEGER_VALUE
    @Function("INTEGER_VALUE")
    @FunctionParameters({ @FunctionParameter("textNumber") })
    public static Integer INTEGER_VALUE(final String textNumber) {
        if (textNumber == null) {
            logNullTextString();
            return null;
        }
        return Integer.parseInt(textNumber);
    }

david_clymer@zapazoid:~/Development/VistaShare/OutcomeTracker/jasperreports/lib/tmp$ grep TextFunctions jasperreports_extension.properties 
net.sf.jasperreports.extension.functions.text=net.sf.jasperreports.functions.standard.TextFunctions
```

I'm not really a java programmer, so maybe I'm doing something stupid. I just don't know how to reference the methods properly so that I can be *sure* that they *should* work.

**Update**: using a static import:

```
import static net.sf.jasperreports.functions.standard.TextFunctions.*
```

Allows those functions to be imported into the current namespace.

So, back to the original issue. If set `net.sf.jasperreports.compiler.keep.java.file=true` in `jasperreports.properties` and attempt to compile the report, I can examine the java file that jasper produces from the jrxml. I find that this file does not seem to import the necessary functions (`INTEGER_VALUE`, `CONCATENATE`, etc). The only imports it contains are:

```
/*
 * Generated by JasperReports - 4/27/16 2:27 PM
 */
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.*;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.*;
import net.sf.jasperreports.functions.standard.TextFunctions.*;

import java.util.*;
import java.math.*;
import java.text.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
```

Comment: CONCATENATE where did you find this function/method?, is it yours?

Comment: @PetterFriberg: This is a function in the jasperreport-functions-6.2.1.jar supplied by JasperSoft. Specifically in `net.sf.jasperreports.functions.standard.TextFunctions`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> symbol:   method CONCATENATE(String,String,String,String,String)

The problem seems to be that the Java compiler is not able to resolve varargs calls, the method is defined as CONCATENATE(String ...strings).

Add an ecj jar to your application's classpath (for instance the one from http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/eclipse/jdt/core/compiler/ecj/4.3.1/), that's usually safer than relying on the JDK compiler.

Comment: That does seem to eliminate the need for explicit imports.

Answer (score 0):

I do **not** get the same result as you using `jasperreports-6.2.1.jar` and `jasperreports-functions-6.2.1.jar`, compiling with `jre 1.8.0_77` (also with jre1.7)

My report **java** file has this method in it:

```
public java.lang.String CONCATENATE(java.lang.String...  arg0)
{
    return getFunctionSupport(net.sf.jasperreports.functions.standard.TextFunctions.class).CONCATENATE(arg0);
}
```

and the function call **works correctly** (note that I have not added any imports in jrxml file, nor modified the `jasperreports_extension.properties` in any way)

So you need to check again that the libraries in class path and that you have not messed with the `jasperreports_extension.properties`

Comment: As I said originally, the jasperreports-functions-6.2.1.jar file **is** in my classpath. I have not modified `jasperreports_extension.properties`.

Comment: I have test since I was curious about the function and as you can see the generate java file is not similar to yours (and it works), you see how the CONCATENATE method is generated inside of the java report file. What JRE are you using? how are you compiling the report?

Comment: It seems possible that we are compiling the jasper report itself differently. I was able to get it to work by explicitly adding imports to the `JasperDesign` object.

Comment: What compiler are you using? jtd-compiler? or the ecj?

Comment: @vezult, then you test adding them directly to the jrxml as well, however you have something strange going on while compiling

Answer (score 0):

In order to make these functions available when compiling a jasper report, load the jrxml into a `DesignObject` and explicitly add the necessary imports:

```
JRXmlLoader loader = new JRXmlLoader(new SimpleJasperReportsContext(), new Digester());
JasperDesign designFile = loader.load(fileName + ".jrxml");
String destinationFile = fileName + ".jasper";

// Ensure that custom functions are available when compiling reports.
designFile.addImport("static net.sf.jasperreports.functions.standard.TextFunctions.*");
designFile.addImport("static net.sf.jasperreports.functions.standard.MathFunctions.*");
designFile.addImport("static net.sf.jasperreports.functions.standard.DateTimeFunctions.*");
designFile.addImport("static net.sf.jasperreports.functions.standard.LogicalFunctions.*");

JasperCompileManager.compileReportToFile(designFile, destinationFile);
```

It is important to use a static import. If the `static` keyword is *not* used, the methods are *not* imported directly into the current namespace, as required by the generated java code.

Using this approach, no modification of the jasper report itself is needed.